# Pass optional parameters to a function through another one

Tags: python, arguments

I have a block of code that I have to repeat a lot and the inside changes so I've separated the inside that changes into different functions but this functions may require different parameters so I have to pass those optional parameters to the function containing the repeated block and from it to the function with the part that changes.

```
def  scrapeWeb (url, function, *positional_parameters, **keyword_parameters):
    retval = null

    # Open connection
    with  contextlib.closing (urlopen(url))  as  conn:
        try:
            rawHTML = conn.read ()
            soupPage = soup (rawHTML, "html.parser") 
            retval = function (soupPage)
        except:
            print (traceback.format_exc())
            print ("Couldn't download web")

    return retval

def  scrapePartOfWeb (*args):
        retval = soupPage.find ("tr", {"class": "product"})
        insertInDatabase (product, productID)

def  scrapeProduct ():
    url = "html..."
    scrapeWeb (url, scrapeParOfWeb, optionalParameterProductID)
```

My question is in this example how would I pass parameters to the function `scrapePartOfWeb` from the function `scrapeProducts`.

Edit: How do I get bar to print the parameters that I pass foo?

```
def  foo (x, function, *args):
    function (x, *args)

def  bar (x, product_name, product_id):
    print (product_name, product_id)

def  baz (x, string):
    print (x, string)

def  main ():
    foo (x, bar, product_name, product_id)
    foo (x, baz, string)
```

I know everytime I call bar it's going to have two parameters and baz is going to have one.

And if I want to call both?

```
def  main ():
    foo (x, bar, baz, product_name, product_id, string)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is it understandable know?